# R How do I generate a summary matrix from a list of same dimension matrixes?

Tags: r, list, matrix

Say a list of same dimensions matrixes (over 1000 matrixes, every matrix has same rows and columns), but for simplifiy, the example list has length of 3. For example, list a:

```
a <- list(A=matrix(c(1:6),2,3),
          B=matrix(c(2:7),2,3),
          C=matrix(c(3:8),2,3))
> a
$A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

$B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    6
[2,]    3    5    7

$C
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5    7
[2,]    4    6    8
```

I want to generate a summary matrix M. M has the same dim as every matrix in a. Every element in M is a number, this number counts at the same position on every matrix in the list, how many of them greater than a specific value `g_value`.

For example, if `g_value = 2`, `M[1,1]` will equal to `1`, as only`C[1,1]` is > 2 among `A[1,1], B[1,1], C[1,1]`. 
Therefore, `M` should be a matrix as below:

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    3
[2,]    2    3    3
```

After I use the loop to change the value in the list as `TURE` and `FALSE`, I couldn't go further. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
> b <- list()
> for(i in 1:length(a)){
+   b[[i]] = a[[i]] > 2
+  }
> b
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE TRUE TRUE

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
a <- list(A = matrix(1:6, 2, 3),
          B = matrix(2:7, 2, 3),
          C = matrix(3:8, 2, 3))

Reduce("+", lapply(a, function (x) x > 2))
```

Comment: the Reduce function works perfectly! Thank you. However, could you explain how this`"+"` works?

Comment: The "+" is a function in R, i.e., `5 + 3` is equivalent to `'+'(5, 3)`. Hence, it is used as the first function argument of `Reduce()`.